# Grouping By Time Range

Tags: sql

I have data as below:

```
Name    StartTime    EndTime  
ABC      10:00       10:21
BCC      10:00       10:01
BCD      10:11       10:16
DFF      10:20       10:21
```

Now first I need a total count for all activities for every 5 minutes within start time anf end time from on the hour which I only have got by the start time as following :

```
SELECT Time,
COUNT(*) as [Count]
FROM
(SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(5),
DATEADD(MINUTE,
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'20000101',StartTime)/5.0)*5
,'20000101'),108)
FROM tableName) AS Time(Time)
GROUP BY Time
```

This gives me my totals every 5 mins as below :

```
10:00 2 (between 10:00 and 10:04:59)
10:05 0 
10:10 1
10:15 0
etc.....
```

Now I need to count the activities between start time and end time

```
10:00 2 (between 10:00 and 10:04:59)
10:05 1 
10:10 2
10:15 2
etc.....
```

Comment: sql server I presume?

Comment: So what's wrong with your query and what is your question for us?

Comment: my query only using the start time, I wants the period between the start time and end time such as start time is 09:00, end time is 09:14.... counter should be 09:00 1, 09:05 1, 09:10 1